# ubuntu is detecting display (as a hardware) but not as display

Tags: usb, 22.04, display, intel-graphics

I am on ubuntu 22.04. I plugun my professional screens with usb cable (in which there is also ethernet, mouse and keybord).
Ubintu detects the as plugged usb devices but not as displays.
can you help please?
Cordially

```
    cskg1281@yd-5cg2303bnm:~$ lsusb 
.....
    Bus 002 Device 015: ID 17e9:6006 DisplayLink Dell Universal Dock D6000
.....


    cskg1281@yd-5cg2303bnm:~$ sudo lshw -c video
      *-display                 
           description: VGA compatible controller
           produit: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
           fabricant: Intel Corporation
.......

    cskg1281@yd-5cg2303bnm:~$ hwinfo --gfxcard --short
    graphics card:                                                  
                           Intel UHD Graphics
    
    Primary display adapter: #21
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the dock to work as intended it is mandatory to use a USB 3.0 cable (which is capable of transmitting uncompressed video), as well as a USB 3.0 port.

Make sure you comply with those requirements, if it doesn't help, you can find further troubleshooting on their website [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLo97_jNb8AhVEUqQEHfZVDT0QFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dell.com%2Fsupport%2Fkbdoc%2Fen-uk%2F000132058%2Fhow-to-use-and-troubleshoot-dell-universal-dock-d6000&usg=AOvVaw0PIS4e4sda2EJK4UM3Dhtg).